# How do I find the real general solution of this third order ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this inhomogenous ODE
$$y'''-y''+y'-y= 2e^{ \omega x} $$
where $ \omega \in \mathbb{R} $

I want to find the real (!) general solution to it.

The problem starts in the beginning:

The characteristic polynomial is $ \lambda^3- \lambda^2 + \lambda - 1 = 0 $

so $ \lambda_1= 1, \lambda_2= i, \lambda_3=-i $

How do I get to the real solution? any help very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\omega\neq1$ we look for a particular integral (PI) we look for a solution of the form $y_{PI}(x)=Ce^{\omega x}$ and substituting into the differential equation gives $C= \frac{2}{(\omega -1)({\omega}^{2}+1)}$. Then using the  Euler's formula $e^{i\theta}=cos(\theta)+isin(\theta)$ we have the general solution to be $y(x)=\frac{2e^{\omega x}}{(\omega -1)({\omega}^{2}+1)}+c_{1}cos(x)+c_{2}sin(x)+c_{3}e^{x}$.

For $\omega=1$ we look for a particular integral of the form $y=Bxe^{x}$ and substituting into the ODE gives B=1 and hence the general solution in this case is $y(x)=c_{1}cos(x)+c_{2}sin(x)+c_{3}e^{x}+xe^{x}$.